# Best way to unset a flag in C when using Enum that is signed

Tags: c, enums, flags, xc8, enum-flags

I'm trying to use enum in C to create a flags variable, as discussed here: [Flags, enum (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631266/flags-enum-c)

### How should I reset a single enum flag, when the compiler represents the enum as signed?

**Problem:**

Say I declare my flags type like this:

```
typedef enum {       
     FLAGS_A = 1 << 0,
     FLAGS_B = 1 << 1,
     FLAGS_C = 1 << 2,
     FLAGS_D = 1 << 3     
} flags_t;

flags_t flags;
```

I would like to reset a flag like this:

```
flags |=   FLAGS_A;   // Set A
flags &= (~FLAGS_A);  // Reset A
```

However the compiler (Microchip XC8 Compiler V2.32) throws an error because bitwise operators should only be used on unsigned types. It looks like the enum is actually a signed integer under the hood.

Based on this question, it looks like there's no good way to force the compiler to use unsigned for enum: [Is there a way to make an enum unsigned in the C90 standard? (MISRA-C 2004 compliant)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635833/is-there-a-way-to-make-an-enum-unsigned-in-the-c90-standard-misra-c-2004-compl)

**Things I've Tried:**

One workaround I found was to add a special enumerated variable that has all the other flags set. I can use that as a mask to reset flag A:

```
typedef enum {
     ....
     FLAGS_RESET_A  = (FLAGS_B | FLAGS_C | FLAGS_D) 
} flags_t

flag_t flags &= (FLAGS_RESET_A);  // Reset A
```

This workaround is cumbersome. Any time I modify the flags type, such as adding a flag, I also have to remember to modify all the reset masks. I'm hoping there is a method that preserves the enum as a "single source of truth" for the flag definitions.

Another workaround is type casting to an unsigned integer, but that defeats the safety of using an enumerated type.

Comment: Re “the safety of using an enumerated type”: The C standard does not provide much safety with enumerated types. Your compiler and compliance-checking tools might try, but consider that if `foo` is some enumeration constant, `~foo` is a generally not a value in the enumeration, so you are outside of type safety anyway, even if you resolve the signedness issue.

Comment: This is probably why people usually use macros instead of enums for bitmasks.  `#define FLAGS_A (1U << 0)` etc.

Comment: On the other hand, I am pretty sure `~` is supposed to work on signed types, so this may be a bug or non-conformance in your compiler.  (In principle the results might be strange if your compiler does something strange, like representing `1` with some binary value other than `0b000...0001`, but that seems unlikely.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see, so maybe sticking my neck out for enums here is a dead end.

Comment: @NateEldredge Now that you brought that up, I tried using ~ on enum in OnlineGDB and the compiler didn't complain. So maybe this is only an issue for a few compilers. Macros sound like the lesser evil here.